# Code not working: sorting array in ocaml

Tags: arrays, sorting, ocaml

I am new to Ocaml and I have a problem with this code (below). I am trying to write a program to sort array. I divided array into two halfs, and then I used Array.sort on those two arrays ( I am gonna fix that later, so i wont use Array.sort). And then I wanted to compare elements from those two arrays, but my code is not working. 
Can anybody tell me where is the problem?

```
let a =[|5;4;2;6;1;3|] ;;
let n = Array.length a;;


let l= Array.sub a 0 (n/2);;
Array.sort compare l;;
l;;
let ll= Array.length l;;


let r= Array.sub a (n/2) (n/2);;
Array.sort compare r;;
r;;
let lr=Array.length r;;

let merge l r a =
    let k =ref 0 in 
    let i = ref 0 in
    let j =ref 0 in

while( !i<ll && !j< lr) do
        if(l.(!i) <= r.(!j)) then
                a.(!k) <- l.(!i)
                i:= !i+1
        else begin
                a.(!k) <- r.(!j)
                j:= !j+1;
                k:= !k+1
        end;

while (!i<ll) do
        a.(!k)<-l.(!i)
        i:= !i+1;
        k:=!k+1;
done;

while (!j<ll) do
        a.(!k) <-r.(!j)
        j:= !j+1;
        k:= !k+1
done;
done;;

merge l r a;;
```

Comment: Oh yeah! Here come this period of the year where everyone will have problems with `if ... then begin ... end`!

Comment: So, please, work on your code, try to indent it with tuareg on emacs or anything that does automatic indentation and add the `;` and `begin ... end` where needed.

Comment: Totally agree with Lhooq. In addition, remove some ";;" as I guess the last 2 while loops belong to your function "merge"

Comment: Thank you for your help. I removed some ; and add the begin and end. I don t know if it is ok, but my code is still not working, I get this error: j:= !j+1 Error: This expression has type int This is not a function; it cannot be applied. Why ?

Comment: That's because you didn't add a `;` after the expression so it's read as `j := !j + 1 k := !k + 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from your misunderstanding of what instructions are. Let's try to explain it in a easy and short way :

- If your expression returns a value, it's an expression (a `bool`, an `int`, a `function` ...)
- If it doesn't return a value (which means it does a side effect), it's an instruction (and we say it returns `unit` because actually, that's what it does).

When you have a sequence (this is how multiple instructions executing one after another are called), you separate them with a `;`.

So, for example, if I write this

```
let f x = x := 1; print_int !x; print_newline ()
```

I have a sequence and I have to separate my instructions with `;`.

If I wrote :

```
let f x = x := 1 print_int !x print_newline ()
```

You can easily understand that OCaml can't know where the instructions are separated (is it `x := 1 print_int; !x`? Or anything else?) That's why you need `;`.

Now comes the problem with `if`.

If you write

```
 if cond then instr1; instr2
```

What is parsed is

```
 (if cond then instr1); instr2
```

Yes, `if cond then instr1` is an instruction because, well, it returns `unit`, no? So `instr2` is not in your `then` block.

But if you write

```
 if cond then let e1 = e2 in instr1; instr2
```

Then `instr2` is in the `then` block because the construction `let ... in` creates a block under which all instructions are nested.

If you're starting with OCaml, my precious advice would be this : ***always write`begin ... end` in your conditionnals***. You'll be assured that what you write is what you think is parsed.

Comment: Than you for your answer. 
My function does not return any errors anymore. But when I call the function (merge l r a;; ) 

i get this: 
merge l r a;;
Error: This expression has type int array
       but an expression was expected of type (int ref -> int ref) array
       Type int is not compatible with type int ref -> int ref

Comment: what is the signature of your merge function ? (you can get it easily in a toplevel environment)

Comment: I fixed my code, so now it is working, thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm too new to comment but will point out that every block needs either parentheses `()` or `begin ... end`.  Thus, your very first `if` statement should have `then begin` at the end of the line.  The statements between the `begin` and `else` need semi-colons to separate them as in:

```
if(l.(!i) <= r.(!j)) then begin
    a.(!k) <- l.(!i);
    i:= !i+1
end else begin
    a.(!k) <- r.(!j);
    j := !j+1;
    k:= !k+1
end;
```

The first two lines of the while loops also need semi-colons because they are also a block of statements.  Note that you do not need a semi-colon for the last statement in a block.  They are separators, not end-of-statement.  Also, as a shortcut, you can use `incr i` for `i := !i + 1` and similar statements.  Also, never use l or ll as variable names. :-)

Comment: Every block doesn't _need_ parenthesis or `begin ... end` but it's easier to start with this thinking, indeed.

Comment: Does also the While ... do... need the begin and end ? or just tje if statements ? 
I added the begin to my first if statement. i also added some semi-colons. 
but now the word else in underline, and the code is not working.
i used those variables names, so I know what they are (l- left ll- length of the left)

Comment: No.  The `do ... done` serve a similar purpose for the loop.  Note in my example that since there is a `begin` you must have an `end` before the `else`.